# Get Undefined data or double quotes in Ajax Success

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have sent data to a PHP-script via Ajax and want to return multiple data in a JSON-encode. Unfortunately, when I want to access the first and the second data I only get double quotes ("). I have tried several examples from StackOverflow, but no success and I have no idea why. The following part is where I start with the dataType, followed by success.

```
dateType: "json",
   success:function(data)
   {
        alert(data.first);
        if(data.last)
           {
              $('#urlfull').val(data.last);

           }else{
              // Fade in
              alert(data.last);
           }
   }
```

The next is the PHP-script where I tried a marked solution from StackOverflow.

```
$output =  array('first'=>'Steven',
                 'last'=>'Spielberg',
                 'address'=>'1234 Unlisted Drive');
echo json_encode($output,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

The return from alert(data.first) however is undefined, then other times it was a double quote (before I made a change). But I don't know why. I want to understand and to solve. But I can't find the problem as it seems nobody has this problem but me.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If you want to really find out what's going on, don't use `alert()`; use `console.log()` and look at your developer console instead. You want to see the actual data, not some string-coerced version of it. Never use alert if you're trying to actually find out what's going on in your code. With that said, console.log that `data` instead of `data.first`: find out what's actually in it before you try to access the `.first` property.

Comment: I think it's a typo: `dateType` is not `dataType`.

Comment: With the above said, what do you mean you "only get double quotes"? JSON strings **must** be double quoted, [as per the specification](https://json.org/) so where are you trying to get single quotes? And having said that, the quoting inside the JSON object should be irrelevant (especially as on the PHP side you'd use `json_decode(string)` to get a real object, and on the JS side you'd use `JSON.parse(string)` to get  real object, so quote symbols should be irrelevant)

Comment: @Syscall, you solved the problem. It was the typo! Thanks man.